# how to remove this text from introduction package Running with typo3 and bootstrap package?

Tags: typo3, typo3-9.x

I have installed introduction package on my domain.

Question: How to delete the following text at the buttom of the packge: Running with typo3 and bootstrap package?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not why you're suffering from this question while it's pretty simple. Benjamin has made things super easy to manage the stuff within EXT:bootstrap_package

Anyway, you can see the configured constant in the file constants.typoscript. In this file, you can find the copyright note, see the file [here](https://github.com/benjaminkott/bootstrap_package/blob/master/Configuration/TypoScript/constants.typoscript#L197).

You can replace with your own or simply leave this empty!

That's it!